# How can I get printerbanner command back in 21.10

Tags: command-line, 21.10

The command **printerbanner** used to be part of **bsdmainutils**, but in Ubuntu 21.10 that seems to be discontinued according to /usr/share/doc/bsdmainutils/NEWS.Debian.gz

How can I get that command back or find the source from a previous version or find a new package that provides the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in the following way - download [package from focal](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=printerbanner), extract it to temporary location, then copy `printerbanner` executable to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bsdmainutils/bsdmainutils_11.1.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
dpkg -x bsdmainutils_11.1.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb /tmp/bsdmainutils
sudo cp /tmp/bsdmainutils/usr/bin/printerbanner /usr/local/bin
```

and then use it as before :)